# C3.js sub plot ticks

Tags: plot, real-time, dashboard, c3.js

I am using EON plot (which is just using c3.js) to plot real-time timeseries graphs. I am using the subplot because I want to be able to see 12 hours of data at once. However, I have a issue where there are way to many ticks on the subplot or way to few on the main plot. How can I specify a different tick style for each? I am trying to do this in the subplot, but it doesn't work. Below is my generate call and a screenshot (note how the ticks in the subplot make a giant smear). What I would like to do is just have 12 ticks/labels shown in each plot regardless of the data that is being shown.

```
    generate: {
        transition: {
            duration: 3
        },
        bindto: '#TimeSeries',
        point: {
            show: false
        },
        data: {
            x: 'x'
        },
        subchart: {
            show: true,
            tick: {
                    count: 12,
                    format: '%H:%M',
                    culling: {
                        max: 12 // the number of tick texts will be adjusted to less than this value
                    }
                }
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: false
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    count: 24,
                    format: '%H:%M',
                    culling: {
                        max: 12 // the number of tick texts will be adjusted to less than this value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

[image: note the giant black line of a tick marks in the subplot!]